# What kind of motor is this AC or DC

Tags: pump, pool

[image]

I need to know what type of pump this is our motor this is is it a AC motor or DC motor

Comment: You already have 2 answers, but things to note on the label for next time: "Hz: 60" tells you the frequency it's expecting - only AC has a frequency. The wiring instructions list "LINE" & "NEUTRAL" - those are for AC (DC would list something like "Positive" & "Negative", +V & -V or 0V, or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

It’s an AC motor, designed for 115V AC and taking 11A.

Comment: You might want to point out how the querant could have determined this.

Answer (score 4):

This is a Shaded Pole, Single phase AC motor, based on "Type SP, Hz 60, Phase 1"

Comment: This adds nothing of importance.  To make it more useful, you should have added the Voltage and Amps too.

Comment: Could you explain "shaded pole"?

Answer (score 3):

I'm looking right at the speed figure, 3450 RPM. That is the standard speed for a 2-pole "induction motor" - 4-pole motors are half that (1725 RPM) and 6-pole motors are 1/3 (1150 RPM).  That's not really exactly accurate; that's to account for the inherent tendency of an induction motor to lag.

An induction motor is a simple set of windings in the stator field (non-rotating part) and an even simpler "squirrel cage" (hamster cage) rotor made of aluminum cross bars. The magnetism of the rotor is induced onto it by the fields.

On a 3-phase motor, the magnetic field of the stator actually rotates.  On a single-phase motor, the magnetic field *alternates* - flips polarities.  That presents a problem starting the motor. Which way should it go?  So they have an alternate field winding on the side to kick it in the correct direction. This can be implemented as an additional wire winding, or done inductively with a "Shaded pole". As Liam says, this is Type SP.

So this will not work at all on DC.

Well, it's time to talk about Brushless DC motors, which are a lie.  They are really AC motors, because they all the windings are in the stator, similar to this one - with another squirrel cage, or a permanent magnet, for the rotor.  **The BLDC motor *requires* electronics outside of it to synthesize an AC waveform to send to those fields**.  That's the part where "brushless" is a lie; the "brushes" are actually electronics. And "DC" is a lie since AC is sent to the stator fields.

So that is the clue to how you run this motor on DC - you can use an AC inverter or Variable Frequency Drive (VFD) to create AC this motor will work with.